# Https and htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all http url to https.
I'm struggling because I need to preserve my current redirections here :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Can you help me modify this code to include de https redirection. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```